# User Validation using JSP

Tags: sql-server, jsp, validation

i am building a login page using HTML and JSP. But every time i get the error "username incorrect" which should be shown when the username does not match with the table is SQL server. Here is the code for login form page:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Expense System</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>

<div class=form>

<form name = login method = post action = "login1.jsp">
Username : <input name = user type = text placeholder = username> <br><br>
Password : <input name = pass type = password placeholder = password><br><br>

<input type = submit value = "Submit">
<input type = button value = "Register">

</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Below is the code for login1.jsp:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charse=UTF-8"
pageEncoding="UTF-8" import="java.sql.*"%>

<% Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"); %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>login check</title>
</head>
<body>

<% String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;" +
       "databaseName=signin;integratedSecurity=true;";
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);
    String uname = new String("");
    String upass = new String("");
    ResultSet resultset;
    Statement statement = con.createStatement();
    statement.executeQuery("select username, password from signintable");

    resultset = statement.getResultSet();

    while(resultset.next()){
        uname = resultset.getString("username");
        upass = resultset.getString("password");
    }

if(!request.getParameter("user").equals("")){
if(uname.equals(request.getParameter("user"))){
 if(upass.equals(request.getParameter("pass"))) {%>
 <jsp:forward page="welcome.html"></jsp:forward>

<% }
else {
    out.println("pass incorrect");
}
}
 else {
    out.println("username incorrect");
}
}
else { out.println("user not found!");
}
%>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Bringing back your entire table and looping through it in the application every time someone logs in is not a good idea! You should investigate parameterised queries with a `WHERE` condition to just select the specific row of interest if it exists and hashing passwords too.

Comment: The use of statements like `String uname = new String("");` and `String upass = new String("");` in Java is always avoidable because you're creating new objects rather than interning those strings which is a bad practice. Just use `String uname=""` and `String upass = ""`. In this case, you're pooling those string objects.

Comment: @MartinSmith i used WHERE condition but i was able to run my program successfully. But what i want to do is first check username and if it is correct then check password. How can o do this using WHERE condition. Thanks.

Comment: @Lion Thanks for you suggestion. I'll keep this in mind.

Comment: You should not show whether the username or password is incorrect. This makes for a hacker very easy to guess valid usernames and/or passwords by bruteforcing. You should only show whether the *combination* is valid or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're hauling the **entire** database table into Java's memory and assigning the value of every single row to the same variable. Those variables end up holding the values of the *last* row of the table.

This is not right. You need to select **exactly** the row you need. Change your SQL query to something like as follows:

```java
PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement("select id from signintable where username=? and password=?");
statement.setString(1, request.getParameter("user"));
statement.setString(2, request.getParameter("pass"));
resultSet = statement.executeQuery();

if (resultset.next()) {
    // Valid login!
} else {
    // Invalid login!
}
```

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, writing Java code inside a JSP file is a [poor practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files). I suggest you to work on that as well. Learn how to use [servlets](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But i am damn curious to know about the problem in my code. Can you please tell me what is the problem?

Comment: That's explained in the 1st paragraph. Imagine that the DB returns more than 1 rows. Inside your `while` loop you're getting the username/password from every individual row and assigning to a variable which is declared outside the loop. On every loop iteration, the previously assigned value is **overridden** with the value of the current row. After the loop, the variables hold the values of the *last* row. You're making the comparisons on the values of the *last* row.

Answer (score -1):

If you want a detailed view, with your code, just write

```
if(!request.getParameter("user").equals("")) {
    if(uname.equals(request.getParameter("user"))) {
        if(upass.equals(request.getParameter("pass"))) {
            out.println("found the user name ")
        }
    }
} else {
    out.println("din't find it ");
}
```

You will observe that after repeated `"din't find it "` phrase there will be `"found the user name "`.